# GLSurfaceView on top of other views

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I want to show `GLSurfaceView` on top of my activity current content as an overlay. However the content below needs to be visible.

Here is my setup of the `GLSurfaceView`:

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0)
setZOrderOnTop(true)
holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
setRenderer(renderer)
```

And in the renderer I have:

```
    override fun onSurfaceCreated(unused: GL10, config: EGLConfig) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f)
    }

    override fun onDrawFrame(unused: GL10) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(unused: GL10, width: Int, height: Int) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    }
```

I can see that it is semi transparent but definitely the transparency is not 10% as the alpha value. It is much higher. Even if set the clear color to (1, 0, 0, 0) I can see very saturated red overlay on top of my main content.

Any ideas how to render GLSurfaceView on top of my main content and to support transparency?

Answer (score 0):

As an variant. You can display the OpenGLES-rendering in a separate view element and set transparency for the rest of the activity content, like:

```
<com.app.CustomSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/oglView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="38sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I want GLSurfaceView on top of the other content not the vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this corner of the API but from what you're describing I think you're expecting ordinary alpha blending:

`DestinationColor.rgb = (SourceColor.rgb * SourceColor.a) + (DestinationColor.rgb * (1 - SourceColor.a));`

But the API is actually offering pre-multiplied blending:

`DestinationColor.rgb = (SourceColor.rgb * One) + (DestinationColor.rgb * (1 - SourceColor.a));`

To get the result you want, you need to multiply your output RGB by your output Alpha yourself. e.g. For your example if you want a very slight red overlay you should use:

`GLES20.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f)`

This document is a good primer on premultiplied alpha and why it is useful: https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre

Comment: This is not relevant to my question

Comment: You've said that when using `GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f)` "I can see that it is semi transparent but definitely the transparency is not 10% as the alpha value". I'm saying that you need to premultiply your RGB by the alpha value, i.e. use `GLES20.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f)`. Have you tried this? Does it produce the expected 10% transparency?